# Display hidden sub menu when hovering

Tags: html, css

I can't get the selector correct in my CSS to display a hidden sub menu when hovering over "Menu 5".

Based on my code below I was assuming that the correct selector would have been:

ul li a:hover .dropdown-content{}

```css
    ul {
      display: inline;
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: white;
    }

    li {
      float: left;
    }

    li a {
      position: relative;
      width: 200px display: block;
      color: #333;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-weight: 800;
      padding: 50px;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
      opacity: 0;
      visibility: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 600ms, visibility 600ms;
      transition: opacity 600ms, visibility 600ms;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }

    /* Works when hovering over the whole menu*/
    /*
    ul:hover .dropdown-content {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
    }
    */

    ul li a:hover .dropdown-content {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Menu 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Menu 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Menu 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Menu 5</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="">Dropdown 1</a>
      <a href="">Dropdown 2</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I've commented out a piece of css which works when hovering over the whole menu but I can't seem to drill down to identify a single menu item.

Would adding a class to "menu 5" be advised to differentiate between the menu items?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use can show your dropdown div on li hover and use `position: relative` on li like below code:

```css
ul {
      display: inline;
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: white;
    }

    li {
      float: left;
       position: relative;
    }

    li a {
     
      width: 200px; 
      display: block;
      color: #333;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-weight: 800;
      padding: 50px;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
      opacity: 0;
      visibility: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      top:30px;
      left:0;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 600ms, visibility 600ms;
      transition: opacity 600ms, visibility 600ms;
      
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }

    ul li:hover .dropdown-content {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Menu 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Menu 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Menu 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Menu 5</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="">Dropdown 1</a>
      <a href="">Dropdown 2</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, hover on `li` instead of `a` for showing dropdown, decrease padding and add `display:block` to `a` and change some `css`

```
ul li:hover .dropdown-content {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```css
ul {
      display: inline;
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: white;
    }

    li {
      float: left;
      position: relative;      
    }

    li a {
      width: 200px;
      display: block;
      color: #333;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-weight: 800;
      padding: 5px;
      display:block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
      opacity: 0;
      visibility: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 600ms, visibility 600ms;
      transition: opacity 600ms, visibility 600ms;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }

    /* Works when hovering over the whole menu*/
    /*
    ul:hover .dropdown-content {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
    }
    */

    ul li:hover .dropdown-content {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Menu 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Menu 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Menu 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Menu 5</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="">Dropdown 1</a>
      <a href="">Dropdown 2</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```